# What are the limits of an arcane lock?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell *arcane lock* can be cast on "a closed door, window, gate, chest, or other entryway." What are limits of this entryway? That is, must this entryway have a flap, lid, or other type of barrier in order for the spell to function?

And if the entryway can be open such as an archway, what constitutes an entryway? Does it have to have a certain amount of sides? Or could it be simply the gap between two poles?

Comment: related: [Can Arcane Lock be cast on living material?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76815)

Answer (score 18):

The entryway must be closed, it cannot be open.  The adjective "closed" in the description refers to the entire collection of things, "a closed door, a closed window, a closed gate" etc.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you and accept this as answer. However, the word "other" in front of entryway is the problem. Other - used to refer to a person or thing that is different or distinct from one already mentioned or known about. We don't know in how many other ways they are different.

Comment: @chewbapoclypse Except that it's the only way to make the spell make sense and be immediately useful without extensive thought about how it can “lock” an open entryway. (Besides, normally a spell will say how it does something unusual like that.) Given two grammatical readings, one that makes a lot of sense and another that makes much less sense, there's no need to prove that the less-sensical one isn't how to read it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie "a closed entryway,  door, window, gate,  or chest,...."  Seems explicitly clear does it not? "Otherwise, it is impassable until it is broken or the spell is dispelled or suppressed." That doesn't take that much thought.

Comment: @chewbapoclypse I don't understand your comment. All this answer is saying, and I'm repeating, is that the only reading that doesn't make the spell incomplete and unusable is “a closed [door, window, gate, chest, or other entryway]”, as opposed to the incomplete and confusion-laden “a closed [door, window, gate, chest], or other entryway” or even “a [closed door], window, gate, chest, or other entryway.”

Comment: I read the phrase "other entryway" as meaning things like trapdoors, hatches, gratings, and so on.

Comment: [link](http://theeditorsblog.net/2015/08/08/one-adjective-paired-with-multiple-nouns-a-readers-question) this explains what is wrong with how the spell description is written. There are least two other ways of writing this description to explicitly state that closed applies to all the nouns in the list. @GreenstoneWalker I have thought about those too, however why would you lock a trapdoor? The others I understand, but not trapdoors. Perhaps, to disable them I guess. Personally, I don't see what is wrong with thinking it could work that way.

Comment: @chewbapoclypse "why would you lock a trapdoor?" - what exactly do you think trapdoors are *for*?

Comment: @chewbapoclypse Despite the name, not all trapdoors are traps; Some are simply intended to be used as normal doors set in the floor/ceiling, and as such, are subject to all the usual reasons for wanting to lock a door.